# How to access a video podcast playlist on the AppleTV 2G

Tags: itunes, video, appletv, streaming

In my iTunes library, I have a playlist which contains several video podcasts.

However, I cannot seem to access this playlist on my AppleTV 2G although all of my music playlists show up as do the TV Show playlists.

In the Audio & Video settings, I have set Show Playlists to All rather then music only.

Is there something I am missing or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part I was missing was that I was viewing the "unwatched" list of podcasts which does not show the playlists. I simply switched the view and the playlists option appeared at the top.

Everything works as expected.